# How to avoid error when filling print, error evaluating expression?

Tags: jasper-reports

Currently, I am working in JasperReport Server and iReport. The version of JasperReport 5.5.0 and iReport are 5.5.0. And the database is MYSQL.

I declared the variable Dr like the following where `am_primeamt` is coming from SQL query.

```
<variable name="Dr" class="java.lang.Double">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[($F{am_primeamt} > 0 ? $F{am_primeamt} : 0 )]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

And tried to show like following:

```
<textField pattern="#,##0.00">
<reportElement x="427" y="0" width="82" height="20" uuid="332ceda3-5237-40b5-a0ef-3aad009a7911">
    <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[$V{Dr} != 0]]></printWhenExpression>
</reportElement>
<textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
<textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$V{Dr}]]></textFieldExpression>
```

When I am trying to see the preview it's showing the following  error:

> Error filling print... Error evaluating expression :      Source text : $V{Dr} != 0 
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRExpressionEvalException: Error evaluating expression :      Source text : $V{Dr} != 0      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluate(JREvaluator.java:244)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.evaluate(JRCalculator.java:591)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRCalculator.evaluate(JRCalculator.java:559)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElement.evaluateExpression(JRFillElement.java:1016)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElement.evaluatePrintWhenExpression(JRFillElement.java:795)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillTextField.evaluate(JRFillTextField.java:482)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillElementContainer.evaluate(JRFillElementContainer.java:259)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillBand.evaluate(JRFillBand.java:456)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillColumnBand(JRVerticalFiller.java:2057)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillDetail(JRVerticalFiller.java:778)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReportStart(JRVerticalFiller.java:288)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:151)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:932)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:845)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:87)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:446)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:276)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:745)      at com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.IReportCompiler.run(IReportCompiler.java:891)      at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Task.run(RequestProcessor.java:572)      at org.openide.util.RequestProcessor$Processor.run(RequestProcessor.java:997)  Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to java.lang.Double      at gl_transaction_1454989470091_439976.evaluate(gl_transaction_1454989470091_439976:363)      at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JREvaluator.evaluate(JREvaluator.java:231)      ... 20 more  
>   Print not filled. Try to use an EmptyDataSource...

Edited:
Language is set java from the beginning and that showed the error like this. After making it groovy, it solved my problem.

Comment: @PetterFriberg That post did the opposite to my problem as it solved after making it groovy.

Comment: Hmm,your error is  java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to java.lang.Double  and your solution is changing to groovy?, well ok...., please add the jrxml of $F{am_primeamt} to create a complete [mcve], since probably you have class="java.math.BigDecimal" in it...

Answer (score 0):

<strike>The accepted answer does not address the problem and since its upvoted with deleted users (ask your-self why) even if question does not have complete [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) I have decided to answer to help future viewer to understand the issue.</strike> *The accepted answer has been deleted by moderators, but question remains and has indicated the solution of setting language `groovy`*

The issues is:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.math.BigDecimal cannot be cast to
>   java.lang.Double

This is most probably caused by that the field `$F{am_primeamt}` is defined as `java.math.BigDecimal`

```
<field name="am_primeamt" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
```

The correct solution would be to change the current variable declaration to **same class** or return **declared class**

**Same class**

```
<variable name="Dr" class="java.math.BigDecimal">
   <variableExpression><![CDATA[($F{am_primeamt}.doubleValue() > 0 ? $F{am_primeamt} : new java.math.BigDecimal(0) )]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

*Note: printWhenExpression not to be changed to example `$V{Dr}.doubleValue() != 0`*

**Declared class**

```
<variable name="Dr" class="java.lang.Double">
   <variableExpression><![CDATA[($F{am_primeamt}.doubleValue() > 0 ? $F{am_primeamt}.doubleValue() : 0d )]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

Why does groovy works?, it does automatic conversion using java.lang.Number and use operator overloading to allow direct mathematical operations on the BigDecimal object see http://www.groovy-lang.org/, but before you choose it instead of java its better to understand why.......